# How will existing apps "scale" on iPhone X?

Tags: iphone

When iPhone 6 came out, the non-updated apps in app store were stretched/scaled up with same aspect ratio.

How will the current apps in the app store scale on iPhone X? I.e. without rebuilding them with SDK 11 / Xcode9.

The only realistic option I can think about for iPhone X is that the full screen will not be used? I.e. same aspect ratio as the iPhone 6 & 7.

What makes me think that it will be some kind of "shrinked area" for the iPhone X+SDK10 is that almost ALL apps in the appstore will be broken for iPhone X unless the apps get updated within a month. In reality - This will not happen. Alot of apps will not be updated at the date of iPhone X release.

EDIT:

To clarify, I don't ask for how the apps will look when rebuilt with xcode9/SDK11. I want to know how the apps behave without rebuilding them!

Answer (score 4):

Right now most of the apps are made with [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html), so they are not going to be "scaled" but rather position of the items may be different. The biggest problem is to handle the top area of the display. I checked some of the apps in the iPhoneX Simulator and apps that display status bar do not have any problems. With status bar hidden and without navigation bar there could be problems. Here's the [Hero Sample app from YiLun Zhao](https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero) :

[image: Hero Sample app from YiLun Zhao]

As you can see, Tab bar is "stretched" downward, but top scrolled area is displayed rather strange. For example section separators are displayed under the "status area" (bottom of it), but table content is clearly visible underneath (side by side with black camera area).

I checked some other apps and there are no major problems with the UI.

So the answer to your question is - it depends how developers made their apps. If they've used Auto Layout there shouldn't be a problem.

P.S. even though the display is bigger than iPhones Plus it has "compact" horizontal traits in landscape -> there won't be split view. Also pages loaded in the landscape view do not occupy the whole screen width (there are white stripes on the both sides. Screenshot:

[image: Safari in landscape mode on iPhone X]

NOTE: This is still Xcode Beta, so maybe things will change when iPhone X is released.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is however a recompile of the app with SDK11, so it does not answer my question.

Comment: @ullstrm it should not matter that it's recompiled with SDK11, because Auto Layout still uses the available traits/guides etc. They are not changed with SDK11.  If you really want I can try to recompile it with SDK10

Comment: Yes, please try it! I didn't get it to work unfortunately. I.e. SDK10 and iPhone X

Comment: What makes me think that it will be some kind of "cramped area" for the iPhone X with SDK10 is that almost ALL apps in the appstore will be broken for iPhone X unless ALL apps get updated in a month. In reality - This will not happend.

Comment: Hm it seems, that changing the SDK is not as easy as copy/paste *.sdk files and changing the symlinks. I've broken my Xcode ;) So I won't be able to answer your question regarding the previous SDKs with new iPhone X. I tihnk we have to wait for the official phone release to find out how things look... But as I wrote in my answer, Auto Layout still uses traits/guides as in previous SDKs, so there should not be much difference.

Comment: My Xcode got broken aswell. I'd place my bets on that the apps will not use the full screen for iPhone X if they are built with SDK10